# Scaling GCM Push. How often can you perform GCM Push?

Tags: android, push-notification, scalability, google-cloud-messaging, polling

Everybody tells me that polling server for new data is stupid if the server is yours and you should implement push with GCM instead. Well, I agree and have done so but, I was wondering, how often can or should you perform push?

I have a simple app where people post stuff to the server and have a feed of everyone else's posts. The method on the server that does the saving to the database also triggers the GCM Push at the end, so Google sends out the push notifications to everybody and everybody then requeries the server for new posts, containing the post weve just made.

*But, what if I have, lets say milion users and a new post is created lets say every minute.* This will mean that app will connect to server every minutes and will kill the battery. So my question is, how often you perform Push? Wouldnt in this case polling every 10 minutes be actually better for battery, right?

I know this example is kind of crazy, having milion people in your feed, but its just to make a point, because I cant imagine how this would scale. I figure Google will handle sending million gcm messages at once no problem.

**So the question is, is there a limit after which Push is contraproductive?** I guess its kind of a first world problem :D but cant imagine Facebook handles stuff like this.

Thanks!

Comment: how complicated is the data in your feed? if it is simple, you can include the data right into your gcm payload, limited to 4KB of course. then you can save the need of communicating to your server. But yes, if you really need to re-query the server on each GCM, it wouldn't be a problem, you can send as much and as frequent as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Push notifications are welcome when the server has important new data to show to the user (and by important I mean important to the user).

I believe that if any app sent me a notification every minute I would either disable notifications from that app or uninstall that app. You should be very carefull when deciding what updates to send to your users as push notifications, in order not to antagonize them. If your server can send push notifications very often to the same device, you must have settings options in your app that can reduce the frequency of those notifications.

Push notifications are usually relevant when the app is not running (or is running in the background). When it is running in the foreground, polling the server is probably a better solution (given the disclaimer that you can't rely on the push notifications being delivered every time).

In your example, I'm not sure I'd want to be notified automatically about each new post in the DB. Even while I'm using the app (i.e. it's in the foreground) I wouldn't want it to update with new posts automatically. Even facebook don't update the view automatically (they show you on top of the screen that you have new posts, and you have to pull the list view down in order to load them. And when the app is not running, I'd want to be alerted only about important posts (for example, posts from specific users). When an app sends me too many push notifications, I go to its settings to reduce them.

I can't give you a numeric figure of a reasonable frequency of push notifications, but I hope my answer helps. In short, you don't have to worry about GCM's technical limits. You should worry about the user experience.

Comment: I wasnt talking about system notifications but GCM messages overall. Ofcourse if phone buzzed everyminutes app wouldnt last long. I am not sure how can you change frequency of push messages, I think you mean that on the serverside. I guess your right about when app is in the foreground, fb approach is better. But still, how about when its in the background? It would get messaged that theres new data every minute or so, so it would requery server every single time. This would suck battery dry, there just no way around it, right?

Comment: Yes, at the server side you can control the rate in which you send messages to the same device. As for push notifications when app is in the background - if you receive the notifications silently and don't notify the user, you should ask yourself if you really need to load data from the server every minute even though the user is not looking at the app and won't be notified that there's new data. I don't see a point in reloading data from the server that often if the user is not notified about it. That would be a waste of battery.

Comment: Well, now I am confused. When do you do push from server? In my simple app, I send out GCM everytime a new post is posted (inserted to db). "If you receive the notifications silently and don't notify the user..", well I do this to have always up-to-date data, polling would waste a lot of bandwith if theres no new data, this way youre querying the server only if there is something new... That "minute", that not actual frequency, its just a metaphore that users are posting a lot of stuff, so lot of GCMs get sent...

Comment: What's the point of always having up-to-date data in the device if you are not displaying it to the user immediately when it arrives? Will it make much difference in the load time of the app the next time the user chooses to open it? You will be doing a lot of processing in the background, draining the battery, and the user won't even be aware of it. Perhaps Apple had a good reason not to allow the app to receive push notification data and process it until the user takes an action. Android gives you more liberty, but you should be careful in how you use it.

Comment: I believe you should push from the server only updates that are important to your user, and when you do, your logic should let the user know these updates are available. If you must send updates when the app is in the background (or not running), your server should group the updates and send them not too often (i.e. not immediately after each DB update). I'm not suggesting to poll while the app is not in the foreground. And if it's in the foreground, even then the polling can be done infrequently as a backup to push notifications (which are not guaranteed to be delivered).

Comment: Yes youre right, pushing without notification is stupid. How about if would collect those gcm messages, increment some counter to indicate there is something new, and then on application start fetch updates if there are some?

Comment: I see don't see what benefit that counter would give you (since you don't display it to the user - in iOS you could've displayed it as a badge). When the application starts, you should always fetch updates from the server. If the data in your server rarely changes (which is not the case you described), storing that counter can save you one server call that returns nothing (and therefore is very quick). If the data in your server changes all the time, the counter will likely be positive every time the application starts, so you'll call the server anyway, and that counter won't help you.