# When to resync not-notification-worthy data after receiving GCM tickle?

Tags: android, push-notification, synchronization, google-cloud-messaging

I was wondering, when do you requery your server after receiveing GCM message, that is not "notification-worthy"? Should I even use it for this?

**Lets take Facebook-like application and the event of somebody posting a status update.**

**My naive implementation of this would be as follows.** 
The server method that inserts the status into database, and then generates a gcm message to everyone who is friends with the person who made the post.

*Now, in the GCMIntentService.onMessage() you receive the tickle. What do you do now?*

1) Requery the server for new data right there? This means it would download stuff even tho the app is not running. (battery?)

2) Save some flag (indicating there is new data to be synced) in the preferences and next time the app is started,read that flag in onCreate() and requery server if neccessary?

3) Save the flag, do a broadcast to the activity. The activity, if running, receives the broadcast and shows some toast (crouton) that theres new data and allows user to click refresh (like Facebook does). If its not running, just save the flag and load new stuff on apps next start, if flag is raised.

4) I shouldnt use GCM for not notification-worthy stuff

Ideas?

Comment: Basically, this question is a duplicate of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513861/scaling-gcm-push-how-often-can-you-perform-gcm-push). You could have simply edited that question instead of posting a new one.

Comment: I think the 3 would be the right approach. Also don't do long running operations in BroadcastReceivers! Create a service if it's really needed or use WakefulBroadcastReceiver.